# How do I use specific key combinations to change to specific keyboard layouts in Debian 8 (Gnome 3.14.1)?

Tags: debian, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout

For example, pressing `Alt+LShift` switches to `eo` and `Alt+RShift` switches to `en` (no matter what the current layout is)?

I have previously found a solution utilizing `setxkbmap`, but using that breaks the layout indication and the default layout switching mechanism in Debian.

Comment: in the section 'examples' in 'man 5 keyboard' there are three examples that could be useful for you.

Comment: Changing to a specific layout used to be trivial, either via `gsettings` with e.g. `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources current 1` or via `dbus`: `org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Keyboard /org/gnome/SettingsDaemon/Keyboard org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Keyboard.SetInputSource 1` Sadly these no longer work with gnome 3.14 or later. The code has been [moved from gnome-settings-daemon to gnome-shell](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/commits-list/2014-September/msg03856.html) - maybe you could ask a question on their mailing list and post an answer here if you manage to make it work.